# Kubuntu not shutting down

Tags: ubuntu, kde, shutdown, kubuntu

I just built a workstation that is running Kubuntu 23.10 (Kubuntu is basically Ubuntu + KDE Plasma desktop) with the 6.5.0-14-generic kernel.
Specs: ASUS Pro WS WRX80e-sage SE Wifi ii motherboard; Threadripper Pro 5955WX, Nvidia RTX A6000 Ada GPU.

Neither power-off nor sleep works; nor does `shutdown -P now`. The screen goes dark but the fan speed increases and the machine is clearly still on (or could be rebooting -- I can't tell). The only way to shut it off is to hold down the physical power button.  Boot is also flaky -- sometimes takes 4 or 5 tries to get it running -- but adding `nosplash nouveau.modeset=0` has helped, and for now, the shutdown problems are a bigger concern.  I had the same problems on Ubuntu 22.04 and on Linux Mint.

I have the latest, correct Nvidia drivers installed (535-server) and I've tried many tweaks to grub, without success. Looking at `journalctl`, I see a lot of errors relating to `sddm` and `sddm-helper`, including "*sddm.service: Processes still around after final SIGKILL*". Do any of you Linux wizards know if that could be causing the shutdown problem, or what could be causing `sddm.service` to hang around?

UPDATE 1: The [REISUO shutdown method](https://blog.kember.net/posts/2008-04-reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/) shuts down correctly, but then runs into problems on restart (black screen, hanging, etc).

UPDATE 2: It will suspend correctly using the [pm-utils package](https://linux-packages.com/ubuntu-jammy-jellyfish/package/pm-utils), but hibernation with the same package fails.

```bash
sudo apt install pm-utils
sudo pm-suspend #works
sudo pm-hibernate #fails (screen goes black but machine stays on)
```

Here is a sample of the output that refers to `sddm`:

```bash
journalctl -u sddm

Sep 27 22:53:55 mlbox1 sddm-helper[2103]: Starting: "/etc/sddm/Xsession \"/usr/bin/startplasma-x11\""
Sep 27 22:53:55 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Session started
Sep 27 23:04:35 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Authentication error: "Process crashed"
Sep 27 23:04:35 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Auth: sddm-helper crashed (exit code 15)
Sep 27 23:04:35 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Authentication error: "Process crashed"
Sep 27 23:04:35 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Auth: sddm-helper exited with 15
Sep 27 23:04:35 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Socket server stopping...
Sep 27 23:04:35 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Socket server stopped.
Sep 27 23:04:35 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Display server stopping...
Sep 27 23:04:35 mlbox1 systemd[1]: Stopping sddm.service - Simple Desktop Display Manager...
Sep 27 23:04:35 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Display server stopped.
Sep 27 23:04:35 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Running display stop script  "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xstop"
Sep 27 23:04:37 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Removing display ":0" ...
Sep 27 23:04:37 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Adding new display on vt 1 ...
Sep 27 23:04:37 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Loading theme configuration from ""
Sep 27 23:04:37 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Display server starting...
Sep 27 23:04:37 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Adding cookie to "/var/run/sddm/{364427b8-4ed0-4b37-89a2-b6fb0d38af9d}"
Sep 27 23:04:37 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Running: /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{364427b8-4ed0-4b37-89a2-b6fb0d38af9d} -background none -noreset -displayfd 18 -seat seat0 vt1
Sep 27 23:04:38 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Setting default cursor
Sep 27 23:04:38 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Running display setup script  "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup"
Sep 27 23:04:38 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Display server started.
Sep 27 23:04:38 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Socket server starting...
Sep 27 23:04:38 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Socket server started.
Sep 27 23:04:38 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Loading theme configuration from "/usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme/theme.conf"
Sep 27 23:04:38 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Greeter starting...
Sep 27 23:04:38 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Signal received: SIGTERM
Sep 27 23:04:38 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Socket server stopping...
Sep 27 23:04:38 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Socket server stopped.
Sep 27 23:04:38 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Display server stopping...
Sep 27 23:04:38 mlbox1 sddm-helper[29413]: [PAM] Starting...
Sep 27 23:04:38 mlbox1 sddm-helper[29413]: [PAM] Authenticating...
Sep 27 23:04:38 mlbox1 sddm-helper[29413]: [PAM] returning.
Sep 27 23:04:43 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: Display server stopping...
Sep 27 23:04:48 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: QProcess: Destroyed while process ("/usr/bin/X") is still running.
Sep 27 23:05:18 mlbox1 sddm[1939]: QProcess: Destroyed while process ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sddm/sddm-helper") is still running.
Sep 27 23:06:48 mlbox1 systemd[1]: sddm.service: State 'final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Sep 27 23:06:48 mlbox1 systemd[1]: sddm.service: Killing process 29379 (Xorg) with signal SIGKILL.
Sep 27 23:08:18 mlbox1 systemd[1]: sddm.service: Processes still around after final SIGKILL. Entering failed mode.
Sep 27 23:08:18 mlbox1 systemd[1]: sddm.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Sep 27 23:08:18 mlbox1 systemd[1]: sddm.service: Unit process 29379 (Xorg) remains running after unit stopped.
Sep 27 23:08:18 mlbox1 systemd[1]: Stopped sddm.service - Simple Desktop Display Manager.
Sep 27 23:08:18 mlbox1 systemd[1]: sddm.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Sep 27 23:08:18 mlbox1 systemd[1]: sddm.service: Failed to enqueue OnFailure= job, ignoring: Transaction for plymouth-quit.service/start is destructive (local-fs.target has 'stop' job queued, but 'start' i>
Sep 27 23:08:18 mlbox1 systemd[1]: sddm.service: Consumed 3min 55.135s CPU time.
-- Boot a540e2f3bc6147c686be543095c0fd9b --
Sep 27 23:09:58 mlbox1 systemd[1]: Starting sddm.service - Simple Desktop Display Manager...
Sep 27 23:09:58 mlbox1 systemd[1]: Started sddm.service - Simple Desktop Display Manager.
```

Comment: Does [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=280561) look familiar?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that.  Looks like the fix in that case was to replace `sddm` with `sddm-git`, but looking at github I only see one project called `sddm`, and I've asked my question on their Issues board as well.  BTW I'm using X11, so I don't think mine is a Wayland problem.

Comment: are you using the default desktop theme without any modifications?

Comment: @Andra yes I am

Comment: can you try a live usb with not-ubuntu based distro and perform shutdown and see what happens? and, if you run a live usb with your kubuntu/ubuntu/mint, can you shutdown?

Comment: @Andra interesting question.  Arch shut down immediately, no problem.  Ubuntu didn't work well in the "Try Ubuntu" mode (mostly frozen keyboard) and using the REISUB method caused a black screen but the machine kept running.  Any thoughts on how to interpret that? Also, from searching the logs with `journalctl` I'm starting to think that `snapd` may be involved.  I've removed most snaps but not yet `snapd` itself (kind of hoping I don't have to).  It shut down once (first time ever) but then the problem returned.

Comment: errm, smth to do with hardware? Btw it must be something other but I had once problems with booting ubuntu-based distros and it could be solved with `video=SVIDEO-1:d` in boot options, maybe try this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ironically, I fixed the problem the way so many similar serious problems seem to end -- with a software update.  In this case, the key was a BIOS update posted by the manufacturer of the motherboard, dated Jan 19 2024, available at the [support page for the ASUS Pro WS WRX80e-sage SE Wifi ii motherboard](https://www.asus.com/us/motherboards-components/motherboards/workstation/pro-ws-wrx80e-sage-se-wifi-ii/helpdesk_bios/?model2Name=Pro-WS-WRX80E-SAGE-SE-WIFI-II).  It claimed to "Improve system stability," which is a major understatement.

The update caused havoc at first: the computer became unresponsive and wouldn't boot, then after much head-banging it began to boot but I could only get to the BIOS menu after which the screen would go black; then it wouldn't connect to Wifi, claimed to have no bluetooth adapters, and other nonsense. If you try it, I recommend having a *wired* mouse and keyboard handy, plus an ethernet connection to the internet if possible.  Those can save you a lot of headache when wifi or bluetooth don't work.

In the end, I did the following:

1. Updated the motherboard firmware (available on the same support site) -- a process that is done remotely from a second machine;
2. Updated the BIOS a second time (you plug a USB stick into a special slot), and
3. When it finally began to work properly, then I updated Kubuntu.

Now it all works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be related but I have been dealing with a similar issue for months. My PC would always hang on the shutdown screen. I finally got around to digging into it a little more after just dealing with it this whole time. It turns out **wpa_supplicant** was what was preventing it from shutting down so I tried unplugging my usb wifi dongle and it immediately fixed it. My PC now shuts down almost instantly like it did in the past. So if you have a wifi dongle maybe give that a try. If this isn't the same issue maybe at least this answer can help someone else that is having similar issues.

Comment: Thanks.  I did see that a USB connection had blocked some people from shutting down, so hopefully your answer will be useful to others.  In my case I don't have anything plugged in, so the mystery remains....

Comment: I think a USB storage device may block shutdown if it hasn't completed data transfer, but a USB peripheral wouldn't block shutdown.